# New Connection Error when trying to use requests.get at python 3.7

Tags: python, get, request, connection

well i've been trying to download a File directly from a URL, the thing is, when I do it at home it works perfectly fine, but when I try to run it at my company's server it doesn't work.

My code is:

```
import requests

url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php"

response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

url = open("teste.zip", "w")
url.write(response.content)
url.close()
```

and the error message that i get is:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='servicos.ibama.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F2F792C0F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

I konw that we use proxy here, i've been looking for solutions for this problem and I could see that this is relevant, but I couldn't find something to do with this information

Comment: have got any solution